# Having an Injectable with providedIn to inject a custom class in place of an Angular core class

Tags: angular

After upgrading to Angular 7 version, I replaced these `providers` arrays:

```
providers: [
  UtilsService,
  HttpService,
  NotificationService,
  PaginationService,
  UserService,
  LoginService
],
```

by the annotations:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Now, I'd like to do the same for these:

```
providers: [
    ErrorService,
    {
        provide: ErrorHandler,
        useClass: ErrorCustomHandler
    },
    ErrorCustomHandler,
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: ErrorRequestInterceptor,
        multi: true,
    }
]
```

Is this possible ? I could not see how to do it.

I read a bit [around](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/05/06/the-new-treeshakable-providers-api-in-angular-why-how-and-cycles.aspx) and [more](https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-custom-error-handler) but nowhere did I find this use case.

Maybe there is no point in trying to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing a service with injectable decorator for root makes it tree-shakable which means it is not included in the build when you dont use it.
Your errorhandler and httpinterceptor implementations are to be used globally in your application so there is no point in providing them as tree shakable services.